# Angular 2: when I need a provider section in component?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, angular2-directives

I tried to search but I didn't get the answer.

I can't realize when I must define "providers" section in @Component definition.
I looked over examples.
half of them use 
1)

```
import { Component, blah-blah} from '@angular/core';
import { SomeService } from './some.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-selector',
  providers: [SomeService ],
.....
constructor(public someService : SomeService ,
```

2) but half of them WITHOUT "providers" section!

```
import { Component, blah-blah} from '@angular/core';
import { SomeService } from './some.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-selector',

.....
constructor(public someService : SomeService ,
```

===

so, I am confused: when I need that section and when I don't?

Answer (score 2):

I believe [Maxouhell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4022806/maxouhell) gave [the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42071824/2419808) in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070870/components-providers-and-module-providers-difference):

> **If you provide your service inside your component, it will be local to it.** So if you have two instance of your component, you will have two instance of your service.
>
> Now if you provide your service inside your module, it will be global and if you have two instance of your component, they will share the same instance of the service.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with at what level you declare your providers.  You must declare a provider for each component or service that you use

For example in my app, I have a service that I provide in main.ts which is then available to any component without having to indicate the provider there.

```html
bootstrap(AppComponent, 
    [
        APP_ROUTER_PROVIDER, 
        HTTP_PROVIDERS, 
        SettingsService, 
        disableDeprecatedForms(), 
        provideForms()
    ]).catch((err: any) => console.error(err));



@Component({
    selector: 'kg-Settings ',
    templateUrl: './app/components/settings/settings.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/components/settings/settings.component.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

However, if I want to inject a component into another component and it has not been previously provided for at a higher level in the app tree,

```html
@Component({
    selector: 'k-Calculator ',
    templateUrl: './app/components/calculator/calculator.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/components/calculator/calculator.component.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, Panel, Dropdown, SelectButton, Button],
    providers: [CalculationService]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need provider section whenever you need to use a service in that component.

Item #1, defined the provider within the component.

Item #2, (might) defined the provider in app.component.ts (Please check the main file)