# Components providers and Module providers difference

Tags: angular

Which's the difference between `@Components providers` property and `@Module providers`?

What do both stand for?

**EDIT**

I've two components: `LoginComponent` and `SigninComponent`. By other hand I'm using an `UserService` from a custom made library. This `UserService` service is looking for an opaquetoken `BASE_PATH`:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(@Optional()@Inject(BASE_PATH)
```

and `BASE_PATH` is:

```
export const BASE_PATH = new OpaqueToken('basePath');
```

This opaqueToken is set on AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [
    App,
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    ENV_PROVIDERS,
```

where `ENV_PROVIDERS` is set according environtment settings on `environtment.ts`:

```
if ('production' === ENV) {
  enableProdMode();

  PROVIDERS = [
    ...PROVIDERS,
    // custom providers in production
    { provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: 'http://public.sample.com:8082/commty/cmng' }
  ];

} else {

  // Development
  PROVIDERS = [
    ...PROVIDERS,
    // custom providers in development
    { provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: 'http://localhost:8082/commty/cmng' }
  ];

}

export const ENV_PROVIDERS = [
  ...PROVIDERS
];
```

I'm setting up all:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SigninComponent
  ],
  providers: [ UsersService ]
})
export default class SigninModule {
```

and

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  providers: [ UsersService ]
})
export default class LoginModule {
```

So, on components, I don't import any Service as providers, I only declare them.

Nevertheless, when I load `SigninModule` all my network request are sent to `localhost`. However, when I load `LoginModule` requests are sent to `localhost:8282`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you provide your service inside your component, it will be local to it.
So if you have two instance of your component, you will have two instance of your service.

Now if you provide your service inside your module, it will be global and if you have two instance of your component, they will share the same instance of the service.

Tell me if you don't understand, I will provide you an example on plunker.

Comment: I think I got it. Nevertheless, what about modules and submodules?

Comment: theoretically, if you provide it inside a module, service instance will affect all the scope of the module. Including its sub-modules.

Comment: What about if I declare a module with a provider for `Service1` and then I declare it again in a submodule?

Comment: I'm also realizing I need to declare so on module and on components at the same time...?

Comment: You need to declare it in module and component, but you don't need to provide it inside both.

Comment: What di you mean with declare and provide?

Comment: you need to declare it in both : `import { YourService } from './service'` 
But provide only in one of them `providers: [YourService]`

Comment: Could you help me with the problem I'm facing up? (I've edited the post). I don't know why when `LoginModule` is loaded, `BASE_PATH` token is well injected, nevertheless, it's not well injected when `SigninModule` is loaded...

Comment: If I have a service that returns data for a component only, is it correct for that service in the component provider, since that component is only used once in the whole app? Now, if that component is used in several places of my application, it would make more sense to define the service in the providers of the parent module of that component, is not it?

Comment: It depends if you want to share the same service for all your components, or if you want a new instance for each of them.

Comment: A little late, but just wanted to point out, it's not on a module/sub-module basis. The other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46161160/12750609) addresses this quite well. Lazy-loading aside, if you provide a service in any module, then it's available everywhere. Lazy-loading is the only way to create an injector scope at the module level (similar to how component-providers have that hierarchical access among child components).

Comment: Yeah, that's a very old answer, Angular is moving every days. 
Everything is different now than you have the "provideIn" property.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from official documentation:

> On the one hand, a provider in an NgModule is registered in the root
>   injector. That means that every provider registered within an NgModule
>   will be accessible in the entire application.

On the other hand, a provider registered in an application component is available only on that component and all its children.

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#when-to-use-ngmodule-versus-an-application-component